# Empty errors in React-hook-form despite it having a schema

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form, yup

My code:

```
export function CTextField() {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useFormContext();

  return (
    <TextField
      {...register("name")}
      required
      error={Boolean(errors["name"])}
      label="name"
      helperText={
        errors["name"]?.message ? errors["name"]?.message.toString() : ""
      }
    />
  );
}


const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.string().required("required field").min(1),
});
function App() {
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    reValidateMode: "onChange",
  });

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit((data) => console.log(data))}>
        <CTextField />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

It's pretty simple. I input an empty field, if I `watch()` I get info it's `''`, but errors are always `{}`. Even when I change the schema to

```
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  name: yup.number().typeError("wrong").required("required field").min(1),
});
```

and fill the input with text, I still get `{}` as errors

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/optimistic-elgamal-nprpmv

Comment: This sandbox doesn't appear to work? This is also a really off-the-cuff thought, but could it be that `required` isn't the last chained function? The docs all have `required` last, which could just be a coincidence https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation

Comment: Yup, the sandbox is the minimal version. And no, adding `.required` to end of schema unfortunately doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution. Change `revalidateMode` to `mode`

```
  const methods = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    mode: "onChange",
  });
```